# Socket programming using Windows 10 and C (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I wrote socket server code using windows 10 and C (visual studios 2015) but I think bind or listen code is wrong.

When I execute my code, It doesn't wait until client is connected. It is finished after print out "winsock initialization success" and "creating socket success".

Help me please.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    struct sockaddr_in address_of_server;
    struct sockaddr_in address_of_client;

    int socket_of_client;
    int size_of_address_of_client = sizeof(address_of_client);

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) == 0) {
        printf("winsock initialization success\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("winsock initialization failure\n");
    }

    SOCKET socket_of_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (socket_of_server == -1) {
        printf("creating socket failure\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("creating socket success\n");
    }

    memset(&address_of_server, 0, sizeof(address_of_server));
    address_of_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address_of_server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    address_of_server.sin_port = htons(atoi(10000));

    bind(socket_of_server, (struct sockaddr*)&address_of_server, sizeof(address_of_server));

    listen(socket_of_server, 5);

    socket_of_client = accept(socket_of_server, (struct sockaddr*)&address_of_client, &size_of_address_of_client);

    WSACleanup();

}
```

Comment: I guess your server sample is not yet complete. (I once wrote wrapper classes for socket server/clients and forgot almost everything about internals since then.) However, next step would be to `accept()` a connection. There are quite a lot docs on MSDN which might be helpful. For the start, this is the link where I stopped my recalling: [MSDN: Complete Winsock Server Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `listen` only declares that the socket will be used for incoming connection and sets up a queue for it. The `accept` call is necessary to actually wait for a new connection. You should google for *socket tutorial C* for some examples

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!!! I thought listen() actually waits calls.. Thank you and Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

After listen() you need to call accept() to get a new connected socket. listen() just starts the listening and does not wait for any client to connect.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much!!! I thought listen() actually waits calls.. Thank you and Thank you again!

Comment: Sure I will upload it in the text!

Comment: atoi should not be used in htons(atoi(1000)), as it expects a string as input, you can just do address_of_server.sin_port = htons(10000);.

Comment: apart from that, you need to check the return values of bind & listen,
and check with WSAGetLastError what the particular error was that happened.

Comment: probably your bind & listen haven't succeeded so accept won't work either

Comment: Wow I really appreciate your help :) I fixed my code!! Thank you so much !!!! I think I should study more about socket programming in c. Thank you and thank you again!